# Missing 3 Buttons in Debug Toolbar for Visual Studio 2022 (F#)

Tags: f#, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2022

New to VS 2022 and programming in general. I am looking at the Debug toolbar while coding F#, and it seems to be missing 3 buttons: "Step Back Into", "Step Back Over", "Step Back Out".

They are selected under the 'Customize' menu as per screenshot:

[Customize Debug Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILPDp.png)

Here's the Debug Toolbar at the top:

[Debug Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/updEm.png)

Answer (score 1):

A few things here... I was able to get those buttons to display in my toolbar, but they are never active.  I'm unsure what condition needs to be satisfied to enable them.

Try this first:

1. Click the small down arrow icon on the right side of the toolbar
2. Select "Add or Remove Buttons"
3. See if you can check the buttons you want.

It should look something like this:

[image: buttons list]

However, when I tried this method, the buttons were already listed in this dialog, but the but the checkbox control for them was disabled.  They were checked, but the buttons were not present in the toolbar.  I clicked "Customize..." towards the bottom of this list, which brought me to a menu similar to your first screenshot.  I clicked "Add Command...", selected "Debug" on the left side of the categories to choose from, and then selected the "Step Back Into", "Step Back Over", and "Step Back Out" buttons.

Again though, these debug options were never active for me, so I'm unsure how they are used.  I attempted debugging a few things to see if they would activate, but nothing I tried worked.

Comment: I have enabled them, but it is still the same as my original screenshot. https://i.postimg.cc/htYQJ567/Debug-Toolbar-2.png

Comment: @DoomWanderer by default, they are present in that list, but not visible for some reason. Have you tried the second part of my answer?

Answer (score 1):

We can see from [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/step-back-buttons-do-not-appear-in-the-debug-toolb/613191):

> The reverse execution buttons are only available for Time Travel Debugging (TTD). It’s currently a preview feature in VS Enterprise for Azure VMs.

You can read more about TTD [here](https://aka.ms/snapshotttdpreview).